# Eclipse - Javascript code validation in JSPs

Tags: javascript, eclipse, jsp

Is there a way, in Eclipse, to enable some kind of code check for Javascript inside a JSP?
I have some code between `<script>` tags and when a syntax error occurs I cannot easily find where the error is... This is very annoying...

**NOTE** in *Window > Preferences > Validation* I enabled **Client-side Javascript validator**, **JSP Content validator** and **JSP Syntax validator**...

Comment: I'm pretty sure JEE Package (the one with WTP) has some JS validation, cannot check out at the moment. Which packages do you have?

Comment: @BigMike I have the JEE Package (v3.7)... the JS validation works for `.js` files, but it seems not working for code in JSP. But, I'm not sure if the problem depends on some configuration I set... What can I check?

Comment: First thing that comes to my mind is to check JSP editor's options and global Validators' options.

Comment: I just verified what you say, it doesn't seem to validate mine as well! But I somehow don't notice them.

Comment: @adarshr probably I noticed that because I'm a bad javascript programmer... :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Right click your project
2. Select Properties -> Builders
3. Check the "JavaScript Validator" (By default, It should be)

Comment: What if there is no "JavaScript Validator" in the list? (it is a maven project in my case)